# Why am I getting Axios CORS?

Tags: javascript, axios, download, get, cors

I have to download an `ics` file with axios,

I tried:

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
axios.get('<url>' {
  responseType: 'blob',
  headers: {
  }
}).then((response) => ...
```

If I visit the URL with my browser, I instantly get the download.

I'm getting the ERROR:

> GET .*url* CORS Missing Allow Origin

I'm trying all kinds of headers and stuff I'm always getting the same error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The server that has the data must grant permission to the JavaScript that wants the data; consequencely Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a **response** header and **not** a request header! It would be really pointless if it was the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing ("CORS Missing Allow Origin") indicates that the server hosting the resource (the ics file) is not configured to allow requests from your domain.

This is a common security feature of web browsers called "Same-Origin Policy", which prevents web pages from making requests to resources on different domains, unless those domains explicitly allow it.

To resolve this issue, you need to make sure that the server hosting the resource allows requests from your domain. You can do this by adding the appropriate CORS headers to the server response.

Comment: thanks! I thought of that already, but still for me the question is, why can i access the file from my browser? Do I need to change the server port? or the User Agent?

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when a web page tries to access resources from a different domain than the one that served the page. This is a security feature implemented by web browsers to prevent malicious scripts.
There are 2 ways that you can use to bypass this error:-

1. Allow cors in your header.
2. Enable some kind of extensions in your browser i.e [cors unblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en)